# Converter módulos EJB e WEB para Maven

Tags: java, aplicação-web, maven, ejb

Meu projeto é composto por três módulos: EAR, EJB e WEB.  Sei que o Maven vai muito além do controle de dependências, mas para iniciar só quero utilizar para controlar dependências.  Tentei converter os módulos EJB e WEB, alguns jars não foram encontrados, tenho as seguintes duvidas:

- Os jars não encontrados devem ser incluídos no build path ou referenciados direto no pom.xml?
- A melhor forma de converter os módulos seria utilizar a opção Configure -> Convert to Maven Project?
- Seria uma boa prática criar um novo módulo (projeto) Maven somente com as dependências, não seria necessário converter os módulos existentes, somente faria referencia ao módulo Maven.
- Qual seria a melhor estrutura para utilização do Maven?

Answer (score 2):

Pra adicionar arquivos jars, você adiciona uma dependência com o scope=system, e adiciona um elemento sytempath na dependencia com o caminho do jar, por exemplo:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>biblioteca</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systempath>/caminho_do_jar/biblioteca.jar</systempath>
</dependency>
```

Mas isso não é recomendado, o melhor é que se for uma biblioteca open source, veja se ela não existe no maven repository e configure como uma dependência com o scope=compile. Se esse jar for código seu, melhor que seja um módulo e esse módulo se torne dependência dos outros módulos.

Pra bons exemplos de estrutura de projeto, pesquise sobre archetypes, no seu caso em específico o archetype "maven-archetype-j2ee-simple".

Comment: Obrigado Júlio, vou pesquisar sobre maven-archetype-j2ee-simple.